# Is it possible to connect to a local Dynamo DB using a GraphQL API setup by AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

It's my first time using Amplify and GraphQL. I've used AWS Amplify to create my backend and connect to various cloud services (including a GraphQL API that connects to a DynamoDB table). I want to continue developing my front-end locally but draw data from a local DynamoDB (which I have set up according to this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html) instead of my cloud resource. Is this possible?

I found this [repo](https://github.com/99xt/serverless-dynamodb-local) however not sure if I can integrate it with my current amplify/graphQL setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't currently a native integration with DynamoDB local, unfortunately. Might I ask, why would you prefer that to a full table?

You might be able to get some test scenarios worked out with a local resolver, however they'd be hard-coded mocks rather than real, useful scenarios.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by full table? I'd like to connect to a local DB to avoid calling the cloud instance everytime I reload my code in development (I need to load in some data for my app each time). I have written a very hacky work-around for now to load that data from local json files rather than a graphQL query when running locally

Comment: Oh I just meant a real Dynamo table. What you described is the same concept as a local resolver - a local resolver is just a halfway step between your work-around and the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use amplify [Mocking and testing](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/mock/) to see if it meets your needs?

There is also a way to [deploy dynamodb on your computer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html)